# NSDateFormatter Strings in iOS 7

Tags: ios, date, ios7

Attempting to format a date in an iOS 7 and getting some unexpected results for day of the week.  Apple's documentation does not list patterns for iOS 7, but the patterns provided for iOS 6 are [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Looking at the day of the week section

> Day of week - Use one through three letters for the short day, or four for the full name, or 
>   five for the narrow name.

However I'm unable to get the 4 letter full name formatter string to work.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

prints "Wed"

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

**also prints "Wed", should print "Wednesday"**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

prints "W"

Is there a new set of formatting strings that should be used for iOS 7 or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: are you using `[NSDate date]` as the date object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noticed, it looks like a locale issue.

Try to force a known locale like follows

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
// or
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There *was* a new [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (released Sept 18, 2013), but that doesn't change the EEEE format.

I'd guess this is locale dependent. iOS might be trying to be clever, shortening the name because it better matches the default locale. Try adding a few different `NSLocale`s to the formatter and describing your results.

Comment: The new standard still suggests that EEEE should produce the full day.

Comment: Yes, that wasn't clear. I see you made some edits to your question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (on the iOS 7 Simulator), I get "Friday" for "EEEE". So this really could be locale dependent.

Comment: Using the new Unicode standard produces similar results: EEEE still prints "Wed", as additional info cccc also produces "Wed".

Comment: Martin R/ paulrehkugler good call on the locale issue. A quick change from systemLocale to currentLocale resolves the issue.