# NSString to NSDate using NSDateFormatter returns null

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

dateFromString returns me null when I am trying to convert NSString to NSDate
here is my code:

```
    NSString *dateString = @"Wed 16 Oct 2013";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
```

Please, give me any suggestions about this.

Comment: try  `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMM yyyy"];`

Comment: @Priyatham51 `EEEE` is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a locale issue and it's sort of the same of [NSDateFormatter Strings in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453436/nsdateformatter-strings-in-ios-7/), just the other way around.

Probably in your system locale `Wed` or/and `Oct` are not valid valid literals for a weekday or/and a month.

Try setting the locale to `en_US` or to `currentLocale`

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

or

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele, first variant works for me. You are a pro :)

Answer (score 0):

For more formatting style http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/quick-guide-to-ios-dateformatting

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed 16 Oct 2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

Comment: I just tried this code it works perfectly ... Kisel Alexander format is @"EEE dd MMM yyyy" ... He is probably missing d ..the correct format should be @"EEE ddd MMM yyyy"... check the link above they have all kind of format

Comment: 2-character = 2-digit/character number or word, 3-character = 3-digit/character number or word. I don't think there will be such thing like luck in coding. I suggest you to visit the link... Try running his code and my code.

Comment: There's luck due to implementation details. I suggest you to read the official standard http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns, instead of a random tutorial. As you can read, the range of `d` is `1..2`.

Comment: well then why using dd NSDate returns null. Don't you think apple might have coded to support ddd

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's a locale issue. I think (mostly hope) Apple follows the standard as written in the official documentation of `NSDateFormatter`. While your solution might work out of an implementation detail, it's not reliable and it may easily break.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella the code works with dd as well. Thanks for pointing out. ddd is definitely not a valid format. It make sense. Thanks for the lesson.