# Cannot get date from string

Tags: ios7, nsdateformatter

I have been trying to get NSDate from a string but it always result in nil.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
```

The string I am trying to parse is '2013-Nov-14 07:39:38'.

It seems I have been making a silly mistake. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: seems fine. Check the scope of your 'string' variable.

Comment: The scope of 'string' variable is fine.(I can quick watch it also)
It is actually inside NSXMLParser foundCharacter function. Not really sure what wrong with the code.

Comment: Possibly a locale issue (your region setting doesn't understand "Nov").  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544675/nsstring-to-nsdate-using-nsdateformatter-returns-null.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Thank you very much. I was missing the locale information. Can you post your comment as a solution so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anna Karenina for hint.

Setting up my local to en_US worked for me.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct. Probably in your system locale months string are not valid literals for a weekday or/and a month. Try that;

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have already posted the solution to my problem. Both the solutions are same...:)

Comment: Oh didnt' see. I'm glad for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me. Must be something in the initialisation of your string. Make sure your string is not nil before you put it through the date formatter.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-Nov-14 07:39:38";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Results in the date being correctly displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still not working for me. And strings are not nil.

Comment: If you copy the above code directly - what do you get? Still nil?

Comment: Yes still get nil. I needed to set the locale information inside NSDateFormatter. My current locale does not support abbreviated months such as Nov. Setting the locale to en_US worked for me.

Thanks for you effort.